# Is it possible to create a stub of android.os.Bundle for testing under JVM?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, stub

As the title says, I want to know, if possible, how can I create a stub from [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to run at JVM (so not Dalvik). Since its part of `android.os` package, may be that is related to that impossibility.

My point is due to the fact that I want to use a mocking framework, which run at JVM, to test the `Activity.onCreate()` method.

I've already found this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/notepadsample/testing-a-constructor) but it seems they use a stripped custom android.jar since its rather experimental and unproven (yet I could not reproduce even with their jar, maybe I need some sleep).

If there is another alternative to mock testing this, any insights will as always be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been successfully writing unit tests on the java jvm for classes that interact with android.jar classes.  I use Powermock to mock out all android classes (like Bundle).

This [link](https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/) talks about using a version of the android jar that does not throw the "stub" exception on the java jvm.  I have not needed to use a different version of the android jar.  Using Powermock I've been able to successfully mock out anything I need to.  For me this unit testing technique is not experimental.

Having said that - the unit tests for classes that extend activities, fragments, etc. become very much mock heavy.  I feel it's good to move as much logic as you can into pojo classes, keeping your android extended classes as thin as possible.  You can decide then if you feel it's worth isolation junit testing the android extended classes.  It can certainly be done if you wish.  You can also consider an integration testing framework like the one provided by [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_eclipse.html) or [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) to test your android extended classes and their lifecycles.

Comment: I was using with kind of success Robolectric with Mockito, but we are going onto a new approach now. Thanks.